# Why Bison doesn't work properly in Windows (doesn't generate output file)?

Tags: windows, bison

Bison on windows does not produce an output file.

This is the error message I get.

```
m4_define([b4_percent_define(lr.keep_unreachable_states)],
[[false]])

m4_define([b4_rhs_min],
[[-1]])

m4_define([b4_pact_min],
[[-5]])

m4_define([b4_conflicting_rules],
[[     0]])
```

**I have solved this question myself, this is for others.**

Comment: The 'expected' form is to ask the question, then write your answer.

Comment: And then you can accept your own answer as correct after a day (or so). 
This way people with similar questions can search SO and find this question and see that it has an valid answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems Bison doesn't correctly handles paths contaning space. Move Bison (GnuWin32) folder to a folder without blanks in it's path.

Comment: If your `Gnuwin32` is in `C:\Program Files (x86)` you should move to another directory. You can move it to D:\Gnuwin32 and add the new path to environment variables. Note: `Program Files (x86)` or `Program Files` has a **space** separating `Program` and `files` and hence it shows an error. -Extended explanation to the answer provided by DSblizzard